# problem with replacing characters in a string

Tags: c, string

Currently, I'm trying to write a code that replaces the 1st, 3rd, 5th character, ...(odd numbers) in a string with the letter 'A'.
E.x: 'hello world' will be 'AeAlA AoAlD'.
But instead, I'm getting 'hAllA AArld' which is not the result what I wanted.
Can someone help me, please?

Edit: The problem is that I checked the ASCII table, the value of the letter 'e', 'o', 'w' in ASCII table is an odd number and the other letters are not. So my program is checking if the value of the letters is an odd number or not to replace with 'A' and not the 1st, 3rd, 5th character in the string.

Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char str1[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]", str1);
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(str1); i++) {
        if (str1[i]%2==1) {
            str1[i]='A';
            }
        }
    printf("%s", str1);
}
```

Comment: Array indexes start from `0`, not `1`. So the 1st character is index `0`, 3rd character is index 2, and so on. Does that explain why you're replacing the wrong ones?

Comment: also `i` is uninitialized, so who knows what characters you're trying to replace to begin with, altho I find it odd gcc doesn't flag that warning with `-Wall -Wextra` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. `strlen` returns a `size_t` type, so it's best for `i` to match that type
2. `i` is uninitialized, and should begin at 0 because arrays in C are 0-based (first elements starts at position 0, not 1).
3. `str1[i]%2` is incorrect math.. you want to do modulo on the index `i`, not the actual character in the string.

This is a fixed up version:

```c
for (size_t i=0; i<strlen(str1); i++) {
    if (i%2==0) {
        str1[i]='A';
    }
}
printf("%s", str1);
```

[Demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/qoWEdMhzE)

**Update**

As recommended in the comments by @chux, it's more efficient to drop `strlen` and instead check for the NULL character as the terminating condition in the loop.  However, for dixie cup programs like this, I'm dubious much performance gains would be realized, and ultimately recommend using whatever code/method is the most clear to you:

Method 1

```c
for (size_t i=0; str1[i]!='\0'; i++) {
//    or simply  str1[i];   since 0 will evaluate to false
   if (i%2==0) {
        str1[i]='A';
   }
}
```

Furthermore, you could bypass the modulus entirely, and just advance `i` by 2 each time in the loop, since it's the even array positions (odd character counts) that you want:

Method 2

```c
for (size_t i=0; i<strlen(str1); i=i+2) {
   str1[i]='A';
}
```

Going down the road of efficiency (and knowing that you won't change the length of the string in-loop), you could also

Method 3

```c
size_t len = strlen(str1);  // ensure strlen is only called once
for (size_t i=0; i<len; i=i+2) {
   str1[i]='A';
}
```

or, bypassing `strlen` entirely:

Method 4

```c
for (size_t i=0; str1[i]; i=i+2) {
   str1[i]='A';
   if (!str1[i+1]) break;
}
```

**Update 2**

After some experimenting on godbolt, @chux is right.  Even with optimizations turned up, `strlen` is called every time thru the loop for Method 2.  It actually looks like to me that Method 3 is the most efficient.  I'm no assembly expert, but this bypasses calling `strlen` at all, and looks like this has the fewest instructions in the loop.  I've created [this playground here](https://godbolt.org/z/67WcdTbWG) for anyone interested.

Comment: Rather than an O(n*n) solution in the first loop, drop the `strlen()` call with `for (size_t i=0; str1[i]; i++)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, even array positions, odd character counts, I will make the change. I've seen the `strlen` vs no `strlen` argument played out a few times on SO... I would expect optimizations to remove the call to `strlen` each iteration, but have not investigated in-depth. Even if they do not, for something as simple as this (presumably not dealing with huge strings), using `strlen` portrays the code's intent exceptionally clearly IMO, particularly so for a beginner. Using it doesn't give me heartburn.. but I will add your suggestion.

Comment: Since the loop modifies `str1`, compilers will often forego optimizing `strlen(str1)` out, thus an O(n*n).  If the loop did not modify `str1`, compilers can readily optimize the `strlen(str1)` out resulting in O(n).

Comment: Sorry, but the `size_t i=0; str1[i]!='\0'; i=i+2` does not work well.  The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886776/problem-with-replacing-characters-in-a-string/71886907?noredirect=1#comment127033293_71886907) was about the first loop.  In the 2nd loop we need to also test `str1[i+1]` somewhere.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ahh yes ... I added broken code. See why I prefer `strlen` here ;) Yeah, what you've said about the optimization makes sense. Back to the lab.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are right. Even with optimizations turned up, `strlen` is called each time thru the loop in this instance. I wouldn't have expected that give the constant, non-`NUL` character the string is being modified with. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Method 4 has an oops. The check `str[i+1] !+ 0` should not occur until after `str1[i]='A';`, else `"x"` is not change into `"A"`.